# how to capture folder as input and pass it to python script as argument

Tags: macos, applescript, python

How to capture folder as input and pass it to python script as argument?

This is what I have so far, but this is always taking the user home directory as input no matter which folder i right click > Services > testing_service (which you see below)

[image: Automator: to run python script on folder right click]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell it where to put the arguments.

```
for f in "$@"
do
    "/usr/local/bin/python" -i -o "~/Development/python/slideShow/scripts/slideshow" "$f"
done
```

…or, if you're only *ever* going to select one folder, you can simplify it a bit:

```
"/usr/local/bin/python" -i -o "~/Development/python/slideShow/scripts/slideshow" "$@"
```

Comment: lets see if this work

Comment: that did not work !!

what if I choose Run as a Shell: /usr/bin/python then how do i capture folder as input for python.

could it be some service is not running in my mac ?

Comment: @san I'm presuming where your argument goes for your Python script to read it — my code was simply an example. The point is that the argument (i.e. the POSIX folder path) is provided to `$@`. You'll need to have your Python script understand the argument itself. For /usr/bin/python, see my answer to your last question: the arguments are passed to `sys.argv[1:]`.

Comment: yes i am doing that already :/

Comment: Finally Got it working!!!, but still the menu is in Services> located here would have been nice it menu could be at second number in the list of right click items