# how to add button to Finder toolbar to call python script with current folder as argument?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, python

Recently I added context menu under services to execute python script but I think it would be convenient if  I add a button on the Finder toolbar, like next to New Folder Button in below image.

[image]

Is this possible at add button on Finder Toolbar that triggers a python script and passes the current folder as argument  ?

Comment: This is most likely possible by making the same service which I assume you did in Automator into a app and then holding the `option`+ `command` keys and drag the app on to a finder window tool bar. Might be worth showing what you have in the service

Comment: @markhunte : ok then how to make the service as an app ?

Comment: To answer that properly you need to show us your workflow  using scene shots and code snippets in your Question.

Comment: here is the workflow with the screenshot: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115371/how-to-capture-folder-as-input-and-pass-it-to-python-script-as-argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works.

Download the **Get first Finder Window Path BETA 10.9** automator action from from my blog : [my_very_first_automator_action](http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/my_very_first_automator_action/)

The action returns the path of the front most finder window. It does not take any input from above actions. The post explains it all :-)

Create a new Application document in Automator and add the **Get first Finder Window Path** to it. Then just add you Run shell script after it.

Save as Application. And then do the drag and drop.

I would test it with your code but I do not have the python slideshow...

---

Note from Apple documentation in regard to Third party Actions.

> Installing Actions When your action has been thoroughly debugged and
>   tested, build a deployment version of the bundle (using the proper
>   optimizations). Then create an installation package for the action (or
>   add the action to your application’s installation package). The
>   installer should copy the action to /Library/Automator or
>   ~/Library/Automator, depending on whether access to the action should
>   be system wide or restricted to the installing user.
>
> Instead of installing your action separately, you can put it inside
>   the bundle of your application, especially if the action uses the
>   features of that application. When Automator searches for actions to
>   display, it looks inside registered applications as well in the
>   standard Automator directories. The advantage of packaging your
>   actions inside an application is that you don’t need to create a
>   separate installation package to install the actions. To install the
>   actions, users need only drag the application to a standard location.
>
> Action bundles should be stored inside the application wrapper at
>   Contents/Library/Automator. Thus, if your action is MyAction.action
>   and your application is MyApp.app, the path inside the application
>   would be:
>
> ```
> MyApp.app/Contents/Library/Automator/MyAction.action
> ```
>
> You can either manually copy an action into this location (after
>   creating the necessary subdirectories) or you have Xcode copy it using
>   a Copy Files build phase. If you copy an action into an application
>   bundle but the application is already installed on a system, you must
>   get Launch Services to recognize that the application has new content
>   to register (that is, the new action) by changing the application’s
>   modification date. You can do this by entering the touch command in
>   the Terminal application.
>
> ```
> sudo touch /Applications/MyApp.app
> ```
>
> Or you can rename the application in Finder to something else, change
>   it back to the original name, and then launch the application once.

Comment: well the link you gave isn't working: Hmm, www.markosx.com isn't loading right now.

Comment: Hmm. I out at the mo. But the link loads on my iPhone?

Comment: yes this does solves what I was looking for, and I can do the same way for my slideShow to open. but the path that I specify in Automator > Run Shell Script is going to be different for every user, which means I would have to some how insert the install path in the Run Shell Script for the app to work with anyone. Do u have slightest idea how to do that or do I need to create another question on apple.stackexchange ?

Comment: Glad that worked. I think it would need to be a new question. Giving details of why the path for each user will be different and what you need.. You know the drill:-)

Comment: I've added a note regarding third party action which you may need to know in regards of distributing a application that uses a third party action.

Comment: Hey @markhunte I asked a question separately [here][1]

[1]http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/how-to-pack-python-package-that-includes-python-scripts-and-bash-scripts-for-osx