# how to pack python package that includes python scripts and bash scripts for OSx as pythonTool.app?

Tags: macos, applications, automator, python, package-management

I have made a python tool which I want to share with users. I tried Automator, and it works but in that I used Application > Run Shell Script in which I hard coded the path to my python script, but since I want any user to be able to use it from any location, I don't think I this seems possible solution. Secondly my python script also takes current folder as argument, See below:

[image: using Automator]

In the above picture the path to of application is where I am developing, which is wrong, infact that path should I guess be dynamically generated and the second argument current folder path should also be passed.

I also tried with [platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus), that does copy the content to Application folder and all required files packaged inside Gallery.app(see below)

```
 Contents 
      \_ Info.plist
      \_ MacOS
        \_ Gallery # i ran this guess clicking on Gallery.app executes this binary
      \_ Resources
                \_ AppSettings.plist
                \_ MainMenu.nib
                \_ README.md
                \_ __init__.py
                \_ appIcon.icns
                \_ controlBar.py
                \_ exifread
                \_ gallery.py
                \_ icons.py
                \_ script
                \_ scripts
                \_ slideShow.py
                \_ slideShowBase.py
                \_ utils.py       
                \_ PyQt4
                      \_ Qt.so
                      \_ QtCore.so
                      \_ QtGui.so
                      \_ __init__.py
                      \_ _qt.so
                      \_ libQt.a
                      \_ libQtCore.a
                      \_ libQtGui.a
```

but since my tool requires PyQt4 I included required files too but  again that gives below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Gallery.app/Contents/Resources/script", line 12, in <module>
    import utils
  File "/Applications/Gallery.app/Contents/Resources/utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Gallery.app/Contents/Resources/PyQt4/_qt.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCapsule_Type
  Referenced from: /Applications/Gallery.app/Contents/Resources/PyQt4/_qt.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Applications/Gallery.app/Contents/Resources/PyQt4/_qt.so
```

Earlier I was getting exifread module not found so i copied it too and got rid of the error but doing the same for PyQt4 didn't worked :(

Comment: What happens if you copy the directories and scripts manually. Also note my note in my answer on your last post about doing a similar thing for my action

Comment: The normal tool for doing this is [Py2App](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) for which the code includes a PyQt example

Comment: @Mark: this would be it, i will give it a try...